# What is the best practise for mybatis mapper xml files?

Tags: mybatis, conventions, mapper

I'm a bit confused about mybatis mapper xml files.

Is it better to have each class in a separate mapper file like below:

```
<mappers>
  <mapper resource="org/mybatis/builder/AuthorMapper.xml"/>
  <mapper resource="org/mybatis/builder/BlogMapper.xml"/>
  <mapper resource="org/mybatis/builder/PostMapper.xml"/>
</mappers>
```

Or could I put all my select/insert/update statements for all Classes in one Mapper file:

```
<mappers>
    <mapper resource="org/mybatis/builder/AllInOnerMapper.xml"/>
<mappers>
```

Right now I use one mapper file for everything, and it works. But I am wondering what the right way is and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to use one mapper for each table.

One obvious reason is that you can use simpler statement IDs (e.g. `selectById`, `insert`) instead of verbose IDs (e.g. `selectAuthorById`, `insertAuthor`).

Another less obvious, but more practical reason is that MyBatis manages cache (2nd level cache, to be precise) based on a statement's namespace (statements in the same mapper share the same namespace).
And the cache is cleared when an insert/update/delete statement defined in the same 'namespace' is executed.
So, if you put `Author` and `Blog` in the same mapper, for example, cached `Author` data is cleared when a `Blog` is inserted.
This usually is not the desired behavior.

If the application you develop is relatively small and does not use cache, it should be OK to use one mapper for everything.